# How to apply a kernel patch from lkml?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, patch

How do I patch the kernel from a patch from lkml? 
Specifically this link : https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/5/9/517

I am running Debian. I know how to roll a deb package, but I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: You have to download the source from kernel.org, patch the source, and then compile the kernel (or the part modified) from that source, package the compiled kernel into a .deb, and then install the .deb.  I believe you would use `diff` to actually apply the patch from there.

Comment: I know how to compile a kernel, I don't know how to grab the patch off the mailing list. Do I just copy and paste into a *.patch file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I've never actually done it, but what's in the email is the same as what diff outputs, which you "apply" with `patch`:  http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

Answer (score -2):

Just click on patches that are under *Patch in this message* sidebar menu block:

[image: *Patch in this message* sidebar menu block]